# I think printf broke my newlines in terminal

Tags: terminal, ls, gnome-terminal, newlines, printf

After running a bash script, my (gnome-)terminal ended up printing each new line where the last one ended (but on the next row). I think it was `printf` that broke things, since it works if I replace `printf` with `echo`. Have you any idea what this could be, and how to fix it without having to close the terminal session?

[image: Broken newlines]

I can not provide the script, because of security reasons. When I have time I will see if I can create a minimal broken example to show.

Comment: Most likely something in your script changed stty settings. If you log out and back in in should be okay. Or type `stty sane^J` (^J meaning ctrl-j) at the command line.

Comment: as well as the answers in the dupe link, many terminal emulators have a "Reset" option in a right-click menu, or in the Edit menu.

Comment: type 'reset' in the terminal

Comment: `reset` works, but then I lose history. I thought it started a whole new session, tbh.

Comment: @lindhe, I don't think the command called `reset` does anything other than print some control codes to reset the terminal, it shouldn't affect the shell's history. It does clear the screen, though, but with garbage like that on-screen, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: _This isn't control codes.  This is the line discipline_, and the duplicate questions are in fact https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366423/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298037/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282514/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346363/ , amongst others.  This has been asked and answered many times.