# Shutting down log not left-aligned when using `systemctl poweroff`, `shutdown -r` and `reboot`

Tags: arch-linux, shutdown, reboot, systemctl

When I run `systemctl poweroff`, `shutdown`, or `reboot`, my shut-down log screen looks like this:

[image: shutdown]

However, it didn't always look like this (though I cannot pin-point when it started to do so).  Interestingly, the three aforementioned commands produce this effect to a different degree (with `shutdown` producing it the least), and the start-up log is fine.

Has anyone else had a similar thing happen?  Obviously it is purely aesthetic, but would be interested to know what is causing this.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346363/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366423/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282514/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298037/5132 .